# How do I write a common method in golang to insert record in any of the mysql tables

Tags: mysql, rest, go, http-post, mux

I'm creating a rest api in `golang` and making a `POST` request into a table.

For this I've created a struct. Basically the vars in struct is same as the columns in table named `users`.

and written a function to make a `POST` request. And the code is working fine, the params while making POST request is being inserted successfully in the table.

```
type User struct {
    ID      int
    Name    string
    Lname   string
    Country string
}


func insertUser(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request)  
{
    var userDetails User
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(request.Body)
    err := decoder.Decode(&userDetails)
    defer request.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        returnErrorResponse(response,request, httpError)
    } else {
        httpError.Code = http.StatusBadRequest
        if userDetails.Name == "" {
             httpError.Message = "first name can't be empty"
             returnErrorResponse(response, request, httpError)
        } else if userDetails.Lname == "" {
             httpError.Message = "Last name can't be empty"
             returnErrorResponse(response, request, httpError)
        } else {
             isInserted := insertUserInDB(userDetails)
             if isInserted {
                  getAllUsers(response, request)
             } else {
                  returnErrorResponse(response, request, httpError)
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `insertUserInDB(userDetails)` definition

```
func insertUserInDB(userDetails User) bool {
  stmt, err := db.Prepare("insert into users set Name=?, Lname=?, 
Country=?")
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Print("helper_methods.go : 118")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return false
  }

  _, queryError := stmt.Exec(tableName, userDetails.Name, 
userDetails.Lname, userDetails.Country)
  if queryError != nil {
      fmt.Print("helper_methods.go : 125")
    fmt.Println(queryError)
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Is there any way to write a common function to insert record in any of the table in the DB?

Can we create struct dynamically, or any other way?

Please help me out here.

Comment: Basically you want to insert any data incoming data into a table without creating the structure ?

Comment: Exactly. The Json params come through request body and the table name through url params. The keys of JSON obj are the columns of table. Now I'm not sure, how to insert these data in the table.

Comment: You can do it but it will not be secure

Comment: It's always better to know the information before adding it into your database

Answer (score 1):

Like in other languages, you can use an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) library to do the DB translation for you, for example [GORM](http://gorm.io/), or you can do the translation yourself. Since you already implemented saving the data manually, see this [article](http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html) for how to retrieve data manually.

If you just want to write a generic method that generates/executes SQL queries by matching struct field names you can use the reflect package of go. You will have to identify the structs fields by using `reflect.TypeOf()` to get the Type of your passed variable and then iterate over the `StructField` that you can get by using the `Field()` method on the Type. The `StructField` will reveal the `Name` and `ValueOf()` will allow you to access the Value. Name and value can then be used to construct the query.
For getting a better understanding I recommend you read some articles on reflect. Like [this](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/learning-to-use-go-reflection-822a0aed74b7) and [this](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection).

Comment: There's no reason to use an ORM if all you need is query building. (In fact, there's no reason to use an ORM ever... but that's just my opinion)

Comment: @Oswin But the ORM also has the mechanism of struct. I'm looking for the solution of creating struct dynamically based on the `request.Body()`. If it can be done using ORM, then can you pls share any example to me. Thanks

Comment: @Flimzy, If the ORM can't be used, then can you pls tell me, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I didn't say an ORM can't be used. I said an ORM isn't necessary.

Comment: I added a description on how to create a generic function for what you want to do.

Comment: @Flimzy: I usually prefer code generation or manual implementation over ORM, too, but I would guess it has it's place in the heart of many developers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use package `Refleciton` in Golang
,at first step you have to create a method that generates a query for any given type
of struct, for example i write a method that generates an insert query for given
struct.

I have thus two type

```
type FirstType struct {
    FirstParam  string
    SecondParam int
}

type SecondType struct {
    FirstParam  string
    SecondParam string
    ThirdParam  int
}
```

My insert query generation method is as follow

```
func generateInsetMethod(input inrerface{}) (string, error) {
    if reflect.ValueOf(q).Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        query := fmt.Sprintf("insert into %s values(", reflect.TypeOf(q).Name())
        v := reflect.ValueOf(q)
        for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
            switch v.Field(i).Kind() {
            case reflect.Int:
                if i == 0 {
                    query = fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", query, v.Field(i).Int())
                } else {
                    query = fmt.Sprintf("%s, %d", query, v.Field(i).Int())
                }
            case reflect.String:
                if i == 0 {
                    query = fmt.Sprintf("%s\"%s\"", query, v.Field(i).String())
                } else {
                    query = fmt.Sprintf("%s, \"%s\"", query, v.Field(i).String())
                }
            default:
                fmt.Println("Unsupported type")
            }
        }
        query = fmt.Sprintf("%s)", query)
        return query, nil
    }
    return ``, QueryGenerationError{}
}
```

know you can use this function to generate your insert queries and also you can generate other functions for `Update` and etch query that you wants

Comment: To add other types use `v.Field(i).Float()` or other supported types in reflection